# Posting array to mvc controller via ajax with knockoutjs

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm having issues POSTing an array to my controller. I am sending a list of items and in the items there's an array of groups. The array value shows as null in the controller even though the sendData variable I'm posting has the array.

Here's my data I'm POSting.  In this case the variable data is `"[{"id":"123456789","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","UserGroups":["1","2"]}]"`

My model for the User:

```
 [Display(Name = "SSO")]
[Required]
        public virtual string ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Group(s)")]
        public UserGroupModels[] UserGroup { get; set; }
```

Model for Groups.  You'll notice the One-to-Many relationship

```
public class UserGroupModels
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string MAMUserGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

The AJAX call.  You'll notice I'm using KnockoutJS as well

```
self.save = function (form) {


    sendData = ko.toJSON(self.users);//value is "[{"id":"123456789","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","UserGroups":["1","2"]}]"


    $.ajax({
        url: '/Users/CreateMultiple',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: true,
        traditional: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sendData,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("FAIL: ");
            alert("ERROR: " + errorThrown)
            hidePleaseWait();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            hidePleaseWait();
            console.log(response.alreadyExistList);
```

Here's my controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateMultiple(List<User> users)
        {do something...}
```

When I look at the `List<User> user`'s locals I'm seeing the correct number of UserGroups in the array (2 in this case), but each value is null.  For example `users[0].UserGroups[0]=null`, `users[0].UserGroups[1]=null`

Comment: As Kevin is elluding to below, you are actually just passing an array of strings to the controller, rather than the JSON of the UserGroupModels object.

Answer (score 0):

The items in your UserGroups json array should be objects to model the UserGroupModels class.

```
"UserGroups":[{"ID":"1"},{"ID":"2"}]
```

Comment: Okay, just trying now to get the Knockoutjs to format it properly.  Will let you know the result.